# which syntax for commentating in code cakephp

Tags: cakephp, ctp

Like in the Title: I am searching for comment techniques. The most popular techniques does not work. Like `//` or `/* */`.

**EDIT 1**
forget to say only in `.ctp` files

**EDIT 2**
example code:

```
<div class="users index">
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">/*
    <tr>
//      <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th class="actions">Actions</th>
    </tr>*/
    </table>
</div>
```

they won't work. I see them inside my page elements.

Comment: sure that `//` doesnt work? [cakePHP Coding Standars][http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html]

Comment: I updated my question. sorry for this

Comment: ctp files work exactly like normal php files. Have you open tag?

Comment: Have you tried <!-- comment --> html approach... just a guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you're trying to comment out HTML code using PHP comments syntax.

HTML comments syntax is different from PHP's.

Try:

```
<!-- <th>id</th> -->
```

But as Mark stated below, this code will still be visible from the client.

To avoid that, try:

```
<?php if(false) { ?><th>id</th><?php } ?>
```

If you want to use PHP comments, do it inside PHP tags:

```
<?php
    // echo "blah";
?>
```

But this is true in every PHP file, no matter its extension (`.php`or `.ctp`).

Comment: One should note that the html code will still be visible to the frontend user, though. I usually use `<?php if (false) { ?> ... <?php } ?>` to make it also invisible.

Comment: @mark Yes, of course. Good point. I edited my answer. Thks :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant perfect answer!